# How to create a chronometer in a notification Android?

Tags: java, android

I have the following method below:

```
public NotificationCompat.Builder createNotification(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    boolean running = true;
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentText("conteúdo")
            .setContentTitle("titulo")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_today_black_24dp)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setOngoing(running)
            .setContentIntent(
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 10,
                            new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class)
                                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP),
                            0)
            )
            .addAction(running ? R.drawable.ic_stop_black_24dp
                            : R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp,
                    running ? "Pause"
                            : "play",
                    pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stop_black_24dp, "Stop",
                    pIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

    return builder;
}
```

In which launched a notification in the status bar, as shown below in the first notification:

[image]

To link the notification I do this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notification = createNotification(this);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification.build());
```

I would like to create a Chronometer in a notification, exactly as it appears in the Strava notification (second notification of the image), as shown above.

How to create a `Chronometer` in a notification?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So creating the App Widget layout is simple if you know how to work with `Layouts`. However, you have to be aware that App Widget layouts are based on `RemoteViews`, which do not support every kind of layout or view widget. Anyway if you need asistance with App Widget layout here is some guaidance: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html

Luckily for you `RemoteViews` support `Chronometer` as you can see from developer webiste: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

A think you can acces your `Chronometer` as usually and you could do something like this depends do you want it to pause, resume, whatever:

```
remoteView.setChronometer(R.id.myChronometere, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                      null, false); //pausing
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use built in chronometer:

```
builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
builder.setUsesChronometer(true)
...
builder.build()
```

Comment: Trying my luck and asking on a very old post, But how can i  pause the chronometer using this method( as in pause the chrono in the notification)