# How to insert a timer into a RemoteViews?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an app that I need to show a timer on the notification. I do not know how it should be done. I tried some ways but I could not. See the notification code below:

```
public NotificationCompat.Builder createNotification(Context context, String text) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    final RemoteViews removeWidget = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
    removeWidget.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.title, pendingIntent);


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    boolean running = true;


    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setContentTitle("titulo")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_today_black_24dp)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setOngoing(running)
            .setContentIntent(
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 10,
                            new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class)
                                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP),
                            0)
            );
    builder.setCustomContentView(removeWidget);

    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

    return builder;
}
```

How to insert a timer(chronometer) into a RemoteViews?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: @MikeM. This question is how to insert a Timer into one RemoteViews, the other is how to insert a Chronometer into the notification. These are different questions. Do not you think?

Comment: Not really. Your end goal is the same. Simple test: if you were to get an answer to one question, do you still need a separate, distinct answer for the other? Also, this really looks like a follow-up to the answer that was posted on your original.

Comment: @MikeM. Okay! Could you give me a suggestion to solve this question?

Comment: Is [Yupi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44509913) not working for you?

Comment: @MikeM. In his response, he does not show the time running. At least I did not see the link he went through. I think I'll have to do more research. = /

Comment: @MikeM. Sorry for English! I'm from Brazil.

Comment: Your English is just fine. Lemme have a look. I've never used a `Chronometer` in `RemoteViews` before. I'll update you over there.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank u! =D